# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError. What's the problem?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Error log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.AddHasCasting.getAdditionalCommands(AddHasCasting.java:38)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.getExtraCommands(ChromeDriver.java:98)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:49)
    at org.example.lesson3.SeleniumStart.main(SeleniumStart.java:12)
```

My POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium_start</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>selenium_start</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
      <version>4.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
      <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>31.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I tried to configure chrome driver on Mac m2

version of chrome driver chromedriver_mac_arm64.zip 107.0.5304.62
version of google chrome 107.0.5304.87

I've broke my mind already. Could you help me with this problem.

I run basic code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/chromedriver");

WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("https://google.com")

driver.quit();
```

If I run this code same error

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/chromedriver");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("https://google.com")

driver.quit();
```

I think the problem is version between components.

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly excluding the transitive dependency on Guava from one of your libraries, and including another version. The version you are including isn't compatible with the library. Specifically, the library is calling a version of `ImmutableMap.of` which isn't available in your version.

The solution is one of these:

- Upgrade your dependency on io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager to a version that uses a newer version of Guava
- (politely) ask the maintainer of that library to upgrade their Guava dependency
- Remove your explicit dependency on Guava and use the one provided by the library

Comment: I delete dependencies on Guava and WebDriver Manager. The same error.

Comment: @AGadzhiev Welcome to Dependency Hell, also known as Jar Hell. You're going to have to figure out which dependencies need which version of Guava, and tinker with their versions to end up at a working set.

Answer (score 0):

For me this resolved by changing the version of maven dependency of selenium-java to 4.15.0

I hope this help others as well.